# quick question about static function in c++

Tags: c++

static function in c++

SO, there can be only one instance of static function for this class. Right?

Comment: non-static functions have only one instance too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, a static member function is just like a normal, global function, except with respect to visibility of names:

1. The name of the function is qualified with the class name.
2. Like a friend function, a static member function has access to private and protected class members. Also like a friend function, however, it does not have a `this` pointer, so it only has access to those parts of objects to which you've given it access (e.g., passed as a parameter).
3. (Thanks Alf): You can't declare any member function (static or otherwise) as `extern "C"`.

Comment: I'd add that you can't declare it `external "C"`. That's a pain for C callbacks, even though it's easy to work around (or just plain ignore the formal, if the compiler permits).

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: Done. Thank you -- I'd forgotten that.

Answer (score 0):

Making a function static allows it to be called without instantiating an instance of the class it belongs to. [learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/812-static-member-functions/) has some more on the subject and check out the following example which will fail to compile:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static void Bar1();
    void Bar2();
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo::Bar1();

    Foo x;
    x.Bar2();

    Foo::Bar2(); // <-- error C2352: 'Foo::Bar2' : illegal call of non-static member function

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A static member function (inside a class) means that you can call that function without creating an instance of the class first. This also means that the function cannot access any non-static data members (since there is no instance to grab the data from).
e.g.

```
class TestClass
{
 public:
   TestClass() {memberX_ = 10;}
   ~TestClass();

   // This function can use staticX_ but not memberX_
   static void staticFunction();

   // This function can use both staticX_ and memberX_
   void memberFunction();

 private:
   int memberX_;
   static int staticX_;
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Static functions can be called without actually creating a variable of that type, e.g.:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    static void Bar();
    void SNAFU();

};

int main( void )
{
    Foo::Bar();  /* Not necessary to create an instance of Foo in order to use Bar. */
    Foo x;
    x.SNAFU();  /* Necessary to create an instance of Foo in order to use SNAFU. */
}
```

Comment: -1: You need a semi colon on the end of your class declaration